# Read Word/.docx Documents on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, embed, docx, viewer

Is there a way to show a view of a Word or Excel inside an HTML page?

I found [JSviewer](http://viewerjs.org), but this requires the document to be converted into a `OpenDocument Format`, which doesn't work for me.

I have a document (let's say .docx) stored in an S3 bucket, and I just want to show a view of the document – I don't want to edit the current document or even copy/paste content. I just want to show it on the HTML page.

So I have the URL like this:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/example//example.docx
```

And I just want to show it like this:

```
<iframe src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/example//example.docx"></iframe>
```

But for obvious reasons, this only makes the browser download the file.

I've Googled it extensively for the past few hours, but I can't find anything.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: http://groupdocs.com/html5-document-viewer. That was the first link when I did [this search](https://goo.gl/aiAjbm).

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the ActiveX control name "DSOFramer", but the offical download of microsoft is invalidate, search for others, good luck.